# Add Certificate to GitLab-Ci using dotnet sdk6 container

Tags: .net-core, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab Pipeline that builds and releases my .net6 project:

```yaml
image : mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - dotnet test

release-dev:
    stage: release
    only:
       - develop
    artifacts:
       paths:
        - \\\\some-path
    script:
     - dotnet publish -c Development -o \\\\some-path WebService/Api.csproj
```

Now pushing this ci-file the pipeline fails due to an ssl connection error.

```bash
/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/6.0.121/NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://xxx.xxx.com/api/v4/projects/37/packages/nuget/index.json. [/home/gitlab-runner/builds/t2ywYzPr/0/xxx/xxx.sln]
/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/6.0.121/NuGet.targets(130,5): error : The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [/home/gitlab-runner/builds/t2ywYzPr/0/xxx/xxx.sln]
/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/6.0.121/NuGet.targets(130,5): error : The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain [/home/gitlab-runner/builds/t2ywYzPr/0xxx/xxx.sln]
```

I know, that our administrators added a self-signed-certificate on the server where our self-hosted gitlab is installed.

Is there any trick to add that certificate to the pipeline?

Do I need to change the Git-Runner Configurations?

### Update

I tried to copy the certificates manually, but then I get a `Permission Denied` error.

```yaml
before_script:
  - cp /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
  - update-ca-certificates
```

Calling `whoami` tells me that the user is "gitlab-runner".